# URI Persistable Permission Behaviour

Tags: android, google-contacts-api, storage-access-framework

So I'm testing out a bit of SAF and I'm finding the behaviour of the permissions on the URI to be pretty inconsistent.
Here's how I'm doing it:

I first obtain the tree URI using  `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and using the `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`, `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` when calling on the intent.

In the OnActivityResult, I'm also using the
`getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to obtain persistence on the obtained uri.
I then store this uri in the sharedpreferences by `uri.toString()`.

Now the issue I'm facing is that when I read the stringified uri back from the shared preferences and parse it to an URI and then try
`getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions()`, the permissions I get from there are random. Sometimes the list is empty, sometimes it is having the right one. So my question boils down to how long will the permissions really persist? I could not find any documentation on this.

I'm trying this on an emulator. Sometimes I have the permissions even after reboot, but sometimes I lose them after a long idle time on the emulator(without any application running).

Please let me know if I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `and using the FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION when calling on the intent.` That makes no sense as you cannot grant anything yourself there. You should be glad if in onActivityResult anything is granted to you. Please remove.

Comment: `parse it to an URI and then try getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions(), ` ??? You do not need an uri to call .getPersistedUriPermissions(), . I can not follow you.

Comment: `how long will the permissions really persist? ` Untill you release them or untill you deinstall your app.

Comment: Advise: Try a real device.